# DNS CNAME for www alias not working

Tags: dns, hosting, cname

I have registered a domain name at one company (Company 1). Because of hosting problems, I moved the hosting to another company(Company 2), and registered 'Company 2' name servers as the NS record at Çompany 1'.

So far so good, everything works. Except for 1 thing, the www alias is not working anymore. In my DNS settings at 'Company 1' I registered www.mydomain.com as a CNAME for mydomain.com, but this doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I have to register www.mydomain.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does 'Company 2' have the SOA of your domain or is it 'Company 1'? If you're not sure, use the  [DIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_%28command%29) command to find out. (Too low rep to comment)

Comment: Is www the only CNAME that's not working? Do you have others that are working? How long has it been since you added the CNAME? Do you know the TTL of the record?

Comment: Hmm.... It seems that you need to check your CNAME first on Control Panel, then ask your hosting provider to check their binding. Please make sure the www has been added on binding. I believe this is the problem. Hope it help